# How to display contents of an api call when clicked on a link in a table created using el-table in Vue.js? (Element-ui)

Tags: html, vue.js, axios, fetch-api, element-ui

I have created a table using el-table (element ui) in Vue.js. One of the columns in the table has buttons in it. Now, when I click on the button in a row, it should open up a dialog box and make a specific API call (using fetch or axios) and then display the contents returned by the API call on the dialog box.

Please find the short code for the column in table (HTML part of vue.js):

```
          </el-table>
              <el-table-column prop="count"
                   label="Total">

                   <template slot-scope="scope">
           <!-- Opening the Dialog Box -->
                      <el-button type="text" @click="dialogVisible = true">{{scope.row.count}}</el-button>
                      <el-dialog
                        :visible.sync="dialogVisible"
                        :before-close="handleClose">
                      </el-dialog>
                   </template>
                </el-table-column>
          </el-table>
```

How do I edit the above code to display the contents of the API calls on the dialog box after clicking on the button in the table ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, you can just use html code in the `<dialog>` box in element.ui. `<dialog><el-button @click="fetchData">fetch</el-button><div>{{ apiData }}</div></el-dialog>`. Seems to me you're overthinking this.

Comment: I did the following code:

```
<template slot-scope="scope">
                      <el-button type="text" @click="dialogVisible = true">{{scope.row.follower_count}}</el-button>
                      <el-dialog
                        :visible.sync="dialogVisible"
                        :before-close="handleClose">
                           {{fetchData(scope.row)}}
                      </el-dialog>
                   </template>
```
The issue I get here is that scope.row does not return the current row and ends up sending the last row of the table in fetchData.

Comment: How do I access the current row or store the current row and use it when the dialog box opens up?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following table in my project, where the `onLoad` function is called on the current row of the table.

```
<el-table
    v-loading="loading"
    :data="user.projects"
    size="small"
    @cell-mouse-enter="onHover"
>
    <el-table-column
        label="Naam"
        prop="basic.firstName"
    ></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
        label="Actions"
        width="280"
    >
        <template v-slot:default="table">
            <el-button
                type="text"
                size="mini"
                @click="onLoad(table.row._id)"
            >
                Load
                <i class="el-icon-upload2" />
            </el-button>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Could you try something similar in your project and tell me if it does call the action on the current row? Else I would need a fiddle or codesandbox example to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, The onload function did not work. 
Please find my dialog box code below. I want to make the fetchData function call inside the dialog box because I want to display the contents on the dialog box.

Comment: <el-table-column prop="count"
                   label="Total">

                   <template slot-scope="scope">

                      <el-button type="text" @click="dialogVisible = true">{{scope.row.count}}</el-button>
                      <el-dialog
                        :visible.sync="dialogVisible"
                        :before-close="handleClose">
                           {{fetchData(scope.row)}}
                      </el-dialog>
                   </template>
                </el-table-column>

The scope.row here passes the last row & not the current row.

Comment: scope.row works perfectly when called outside the dilog box. But I want to call it inside the dialog box in order to print the contents inside the dialog box.

Comment: It looks like, it's running in a loop (from row 1 to last row) when I try to access scope.row inside the dialog box, and then it ends up displaying the last row contents. Please help me fix this issue. Stuck on this from quite sometime.